# How to prevent an input element from being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, submit

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent an input to be submitted.
In fact, I want to disable an hidden field in order to not received the value in the params when I will submit the form.

I know the `$("element").attr("disabled", "disabled")` but the value is sent and I don't want that.

Comment: Detach it from the DOM - `.detach()`

Comment: whats the issue with it being sent anyway? Send it, just dont use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want a form element to be sent, remove its `name` attribute:

```
$('element').attr('name', '');
```

If you want the element to be completely removed, use `.remove()`:

```
$('element').remove();
```

Comment: Removing the `name` attribute would be `.removeAttr( 'name' )`

Comment: Something to keep in mind: in practice input elements without a name still get submitted with an empty string for a name. Could be a minor issue, for example because Apache Tomcat logs warnings for such parameters.